# jQuery: Looping through checkbox and storing in an array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox

I have a page with checkboxes on it, and I'm trying to loop through them when a button is clicked, check if any of them are checked, and if none are checked, I want to display an alert. This is what I have, and it isn't working.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('input#addnewwebsite').click(function() {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
            var categories = [];
            var $(this) = $(this);    
            if ($(this).is(':checked') == true) {
                categories.push($(this)); // checked, add to array
                break;
            }
            if (categories != null) {
                alert('You must select at least one category.');
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `var $(this) = $(this);` .. are you sure that works?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `:checked` selector with length.

```
$('input#addnewwebsite').click(function() {
    var categories = $('input:checkbox:checked');
    if(!categories.length){
       alert('You must select at least one category.');  
    }
})
```

Why doesn't your code work.

- You are initialising `var categories = [];` for every checkbox iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
var categories = [];
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('input#addnewwebsite').click(function() {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {

            var $this = $(this);    
            if ( $this.is(':checked') == true) {
                categories.push( $this ); // checked, add to array
                break;
            }

            if (categories.length == 0 ) {
                alert('You must select at least one category.');
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In your code the categories array need to be outside the loop as it is being reinitialized for each checkbox iteration.
Also instead of checking **categories != null** you need to check the length of the array and if its **ZERO** you alert the message.
And you have assigned **var $(this) = $(this)** which makes no sense. Rather it should be **var $this = $(this)** or the variable name can be anything.